# Opening my windows 10 project with spacemacs via samba/mount will attach wrong encoding to all files

Tags: spacemacs, magit

I have a project on my windows machine.
I mounted that via samba.
Then I access the project with spacemacs.
When I run magit now **all** project fiels have been modified.

The actual change is that every file has a line feed with `^M` now.

How can I disable this?

Comment: Were there any files you did not explicitly edit that were changed?  Does the following help? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html

Comment: Tried that already. Not working. Yea all files of the whole project where modified with the `^M`. So in fact all are true to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Git issue than an Emacs/Magit issue. Git provides several variables to control this: `core.eol`, `core.safectlf` and `core.autocrlf`, all documented in [`git-config(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Also ask a search engine about "git line ending" or something like that.

Here are some pages I found that way, that seem to provide easy to follow instructions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings
- https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/